# Converting voice into words and then using them as the value for variables in php

Tags: php, speech-recognition

What I am going to ask sounds little crazy but still I want to know.
How to take input from an audio device in php.
For example, `fgets(STDIN)` is used to take input from keyboard.
Similarly is there any function or anything in php to take input from microphone (Converting voice into words and then using them as the value for variables in php)?

Comment: there's a google extension http://code.google.com/p/php-swift-tts/

Comment: Thanks @hob. That could be of little help for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use existing speech recognition engine with C API like [CMUSphinx](http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net).

You need to create an extention to call C from PHP. For that see
[Loading c libraries from php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2574206/loading-c-libraries-from-php)

For more details on CMUSphinx see the [tutorial](http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/wiki/tutorial)

Comment: Thanks for the answer and link provided for everything. It will be of great help to me.